# Mock class method not being called

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, ocmock

I'm attempting to test a method on my class that calls a class method on another class.  The second class I'm calling is contained inside of a framework if that matters.

Simplified version of the method I'm trying to test.  I just want to verify that the switch statement does what I expect by catching and verifying the call to [DataCapture trackEvent:].

```
- (void)beaconValue:(NSInteger)value
{
    NSString* elementIdValue;
    switch(value)
    {
        case 1:
            elementIdValue = @"One";
            break;
        case 2:
            elementIdValue = @"Two";
            break;
        case 3:
            elementIdValue = @"Three";
            break;
    }

    [DataCapture trackEvent:elementValueId];
}
```

Here is the test I wrote that I expect to work:

```
- (void)testCaptureData_1
{
    id mockDataCapture = OCMClassMock([DataCapture class]);

    OCMExpect([mockDataCapture trackEvent:@"One"]);

    [[BeaconingService sharedBeaconingService] beaconValue:1];

    OCMVerifyAll(mockDataCapture);

    [mockDataCapture stopMocking];
}
```

My verify always tells me that the expected trackEvent method was not invoked, even if I change my expect to [OCMArg any].  Am I doing something obviously wrong or is the problem elsewhere (i.e. bad project setup?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone runs across a similar issue I was able to solve my problem by adding the `-bind_at_load -ObjC` other linker flags to my test target.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good and should work. I can only think of two reasons for the behaviour you observe.

If the `DataCapture` class has an instance method that is also called `trackEvent:` then the mock will mock the instance method and not the class method. In such cases it is necessary to wrap the method invocation in a `ClassMethod()` macro, i.e. `OCMExpect(ClassMethod(...)))`.

If that's not the case my next guess would be an issue with CocoaPods. I've seen several similar reports and in the end it turned out that CocoaPods would somehow add the same binary twice. In such cases it's possible that OCMock adds its magic to one version of the class but the test uses another. I don't have a reference handy but this shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the ClassMethod() wrapper and double check.  I did add my test target to my Podfile and have libPods.a linked to both my main and test targets, is that not right?  As I was building this test target I thought I was getting errors by not having it linked.

Comment: Still no love.  Not only did I do the ClassMethod() wrapping, but I removed libPod.a from my test target and still get the 'expected method was not invoked'.

Comment: I am no expert on CocoaPods. If I remember previous discussions correctly, though, adding libPods.a to both targets is the cause of many problems. Remember, these are static libraries, and adding them to two targets will mean that the same code (the actual binary) will be present as a separate copy in each target.

Comment: Yeah, I'm fairly new to CocoaPods and UnitTesting so I was just following what had been done before.  But this makes perfect sense.  Unfortunately, I'm still no closer to solving my mocking problem.